# tcolorbox: Potential bug with duplicate label for hyperref link

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

I noticed that a 'tcolorbox' with auto counter including the section number causes a warning in the log file and the respective hyperref links point only to the first occurence.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{mybox}[1][]{title=MyBox~\thetcbcounter,#1}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Mybox~\ref{mybox1}; Mybox~\ref{mybox2}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}[label=mybox1]
The counter name is \texttt{\tcbcounter}.
\end{mybox}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}[label=mybox2]
The counter name is \texttt{\tcbcounter}.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

The warning in the log file reads

```
warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'tcb@cnt@mybox.1'
```

So somehow the 'tcbcounter' is properly reset for the second section, but the internal counter 'tcb@cnt@mybox' does not contain the section number, so that the reference link to the second box points to the first.

Is this known or maybe a bug? Or can I, as the user, fix this easily? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @egreg's answer, it seems that one only needs to define new `tcolorbox`es after loading package `hyperref`. If both should be done from inside a custom package or a more complicated preamble structure, the `\AtEndPreamble` and `\AtBeginDocument` from the `etoolbox` package can be used.

Loading package `auxhook` early prevents an error message when using a `koma-scrip` class (see [etoolbox + koma-script: Warning 'seems someone has broken package auxhook'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485295/etoolbox-koma-script-warning-seems-someone-has-broken-package-auxhook)).

So a functional MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox, auxhook}

\AtEndPreamble{
    \usepackage{hyperref}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{mybox}[1][]{%
        title=MyBox~\thetcbcounter,#1}
}

\begin{document}
Mybox~\ref{mybox1}; Mybox~\ref{mybox2}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}[label=mybox1]
The counter name is \texttt{\tcbcounter}.
\end{mybox}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}[label=mybox2]
The counter name is \texttt{\tcbcounter}.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`hyperref` has a built-in mechanism for this. If for a counter the command `\theH<counter>` is defined, then it is used for internal anchor names instead of `\the<counter>`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{mybox}[1][]{%
  title=MyBox~\thetcbcounter,
  #1
}
\providecommand{\theHtcbcounter}{\thesection.\arabic{tcbcounter}}

\begin{document}

Mybox~\ref{mybox1}; Mybox~\ref{mybox2}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}[label=mybox1]
The counter name is \texttt{\tcbcounter}.
\end{mybox}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\begin{mybox}[label=mybox2]
The counter name is \texttt{\tcbcounter}.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

This way the two links will have distinct anchor names and all is well.

If you want this to work with later loading of `hyperref`, you have to plunge in the internals:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand\theHtcb@cnt@mybox{\thesection.\arabic{tcb@cnt@mybox}}
\makeatother
```

because `tcolorbox` associates that counter to the color box.

Comment: This seems to require loading `hyperref` before the definition(s) of `tcolorbox`s. So I would need to load `hyperref` pretty early on in my classes/packages. On the other hand, I read one should load `hyperref`at the end of the preamble. So what would you recommend?

Comment: @FlorianL Delay the definitions of the boxes at begin document. The “fault” is in `tcolorbox` that doesn't actually do `\newcounter{tcbcounter}`.

Comment: @FlorianL I added the workaround

Comment: After playing around a bit, I think delaying the definitions of the boxes with `\AtBeginDocument` is what matters. The MWE works with loading `hyperref` before the box definition, even without the `\providecommand`. Could you point this out in your answer such that I can mark it as such?